# ImageView from a URL

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set ImageView bitmap from our network drive. But i getting Unable to connect to server: Unable to log in to server (PASS): 141.11.11.247 error.

Here is my download ant setBitmap code for this :

`public class ResimCek implements Runnable {`

```
    int resimID = 0;

    public ResimCek(int parcaID) {
        // store parameter for later user
        resimID = parcaID;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            ImageView resim = (ImageView) findViewById(resimID);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                            "file://141.11.11.247/foto_metod/Parca/"
                                    + Integer.toString(resimID) + ".jpg")
                            .getContent());
            resim.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my last code :

`public class ResimCek implements Runnable {`

```
    int resimID = 0;

    public ResimCek(int parcaID) {
        // store parameter for later user
        resimID = parcaID;
    }

    public void run() {

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(Integer.toString(resimID) , "tag", getPackageName()); 
        ImageView resim = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);

        Drawable image = ImageOperations(getBaseContext(),"http://141.11.11.206/parca/" + Integer.toString(resimID) + ".jpg" ,"I" + Integer.toString(resimID) + ".jpg");
        // ******************************************************
        resim.setImageDrawable(image); // I GOT THE ERROR HERE!!!
    }
}
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream(),saveFilename);
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you forgot to declare internet permission in your manifest file, check it please.

Comment: i have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: wow, found it. the protocol in your code is file instead of http/https. What kind of protocol you use to transfer images?

Comment: as you can see i use file protocol. not https or https. it is not a web server.

Comment: but 141.11.11.247 is a domain client. and so i think i have to login, how can i login to client to use file protocol? thanks.

Comment: and now i am getting the Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. error.

Comment: You CAN'T update views in android in other thread, android is not thread safe. you can use runOnUiThread method ( I'm not very good at here, I simply use ASyncTask)

Answer (score 0):

Download [FtpClient](http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2007/11/03/java-ftp-client/)

And use username and password to login. 
Look at [this](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.in/2010/08/android-ftp-client.html) documentation, hope it will help you.

Comment: my images are stored in a network drive and it is not a web server. so that i use file protocol

Comment: Suvam thanks for ur replies but i say it is not a ftp or http protocol to access to files. it is just a network machine, not a server.

Comment: i change the protocol to http. no more file protocol. you can look my edited post.